# Can't Send data from php page to another php page via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a table and each row has unique ID so I'm trying to send this ID to another PHP page to use this ID in SQL statement. I've tried to do some echo statements to check if the request was successful but the echo statement wasn't executed

Function which sends data

```
<script>
    function promote(id) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert("Promoted to QA successfully");
            }  
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "promoteAccount.php?id="+id, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

promoteAccount.php

```
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    require_once 'dbconnection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM staf WHERE StaffID = ".$id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row['Role'] == "Receptionist") {
                $updateSQL = "UPDATE staff SET Role = 'QA' WHERE StaffID = ".$id;
                $updateResult = mysqli_query($conn, $updateSQL);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The PHP is wide open to sql injection because of the use of `user supplied input` being used directly in the sql

Comment: Is that a typo just for the question where you have `SELECT * FROM staf ` or is that in your actual code?

Comment: Usually when doing any sort of edit/delete operations like this you would tend to use `POST` so that the URL cannot be bookmarked and replayed with different parameters. Whilst POST is not foolproof it is marginally better than using GET like this.

Use a `prepared statement` rather than directly embedding the variables in the sql

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above regarding GET versus POST for operations of this nature I'd suggest that you alter the PHP to accept only a POST request and within your Javascript perhaps use the newer and far more powerful [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
It appears that the SQL can be simplifed so that you issue a single query using the column `role` within the `where` clause to verify the update is applicable rather than using a separate query and iterating through a recordset.

```
<?php
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){
    
        require_once 'dbconnection.php';
        
        $code='QA';
        $role='Receptionist';
        # error: missing ` from after staffid!!
        $sql='update `staff` set `role`=? where `staffid`=? and `role`=?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $code, $_POST['id'], $role );
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
        
        http_response_code( 200 );
        exit( $result==1 ? 'Success' : 'Failed' );
    }
    
    http_response_code( 404 );
    
    
?>
```

And the modified Javascript function using `Fetch`

```
const promote=( id=false )=>{
    if( id ){
        let fd=new FormData();
            fd.set('id',id);
            
        fetch( 'promoteAccount.php',{ method:'post',body:fd } )
            .then(r=>r.text())
            .then(text=>{
                alert('Promoted to QA successfully');
                console.log( text );
            })
    }
}
```

---

The single page demo I created to test this:

```
<?php
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){
    
        #require_once 'dbconnection.php';
        
        chdir('../../dbo');
        require 'db-conn-details.php';
        require 'mysqli-conn.php';
        
        
        
        $code='QA';
        $role='Receptionist';
        
        $sql='update `staff` set `role`=? where `staffid`=? and `role` = ?';
        
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $code, $_POST['id'], $role );
        
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->affected_rows;
        
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
        
        http_response_code( 200 );
        exit( $result==1 ? 'Success' : 'Failed' );
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='button' data-id=1 value='Promote 1' />
        <input type='button' data-id=2 value='Promote 2' />
        <input type='button' data-id=3 value='Promote 3' />
        <input type='button' data-id=4 value='Promote 4' />
        <input type='button' data-id=5 value='Promote 5' />
        <input type='button' data-id=6 value='Promote 6' />
        <input type='button' data-id=7 value='Promote 7' />
        <script>
            const promote=( id=false )=>{
                if( id ){
                    let fd=new FormData();
                        fd.set('id',id);
                        
                    fetch( 'promoteAccount.php',{ method:'post',body:fd } )
                        .then(r=>r.text())
                        .then(text=>{
                            alert('Promoted to QA successfully');
                            console.log( text );
                        })
                }
            }
            document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]').forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                promote( e.target.dataset.id );
            }))
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the following table schema and data:

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| staffid | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| role    | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



+---------+-----------+--------------+
| staffid | name      | role         |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 | Paula     | QA           |
|       2 | Daniela   | PA           |
|       3 | Susan     | Cleaner      |
|       4 | Isobel    | Receptionist |
|       5 | Carrie    | Team Leader  |
|       6 | Chantelle | IT support   |
|       7 | Helen     | Receptionist |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: The PHP code isn't working, I even tried my old code with the first if statement but it's not working at all

Comment: OK - I have rattled this up as a demo and found a couple of minor errors which were preventing this from working. I'll post the updates now